# how to use typescript to get the length of an array of objects

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm trying to get the length of an  an array of objects from the back-end by using API call.
Here is what a "zone" objective looks like:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "a"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "b"
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "c"
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "name": "d"
    }
]
```

and the following typescript code doesn't return the length correctly:

```
var lengthZones= Object.keys(this.swimbandsService.getZones()).length;
```

What is the correct way to get the length of an  an array of objects in typescript?

Comment: What's an "objective" in this context? It looks like a string containing JSON for an array of objects. If so, parse it, then use its `length` property.

Comment: What is an 'objective'? An array?

Comment: By objective you probably mean the number of objects within an array?

Comment: `Object.keys` returns an array of the keys of an object and it looks like `getZones` returns an array. So calling Object.keys on the Array object isn't what you really want to do here. Since getZones returns an array you should be able to simply do `this.swimbandsService.getZones().length`

Comment: Although we certainly can't tell just from what you've posted, in addition to the suggestion that if it's an array you want the length property, it's possible that you haven't parsed the JSON string from the backend into it's Javascript representation, meaning that *both* `Object.keys` *and* the `.length` property will give you the wrong answer: strings don't have keys (length 0) but the do have a length (number of characters in the string).

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you need to wait for the Promise to resolve first, then you can access the response and count the objects inside the array.

```
this.swimbandsService.getZones().then((response) => {
  // might need to parse the response as json, depending on your service logic
  var lengthZones = response.length;
});
```